# Prometheus/PromQL subtract two gauge metrics

Tags: prometheus

I have this gauge metric "metric_awesome" from two different instances.
What i want to do, is subtract instance one from instance two like so

```
metric_awesome{instance="one"} - metric_awesome{instance="two"}
```

Unfortunately the result set is empty. Has anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The issue here is that the labels don't match. What you want is:

```
metric_awesome{instance="one"} - ignoring(instance) metric_awesome{instance="two"}
```

Comment: If you need to ignore multiple labels, you can just separate them with `,`, eg: 

`metric{entity="sensor1"} - ignoring(entity,friendly_name)metric{entity="sensor2"}`

Answer (score 7):

By default Prometheus performs `a - b` in the following way:

1. It selects all the time series for `a` query.
2. It selects all the time series for `b` query.
3. It searches pairs of time series at `a` and `b` results with identical sets of labels.
4. It calculates the difference between time series in the found pairs with identical sets of labels.

See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#one-to-one-vector-matches) for more details.

The `metric_awesome{instance="one"} - metric_awesome{instance="two"}` returns empty result, because all the matching time series on the left side of `-` contain `instance="one"` label, while all the time series on the right side of `-` contain `instance="two"` label. There are no time series pairs with identical sets of labels here.

This behavior can be changed with `on()`, `ignoring()`, `group_left()` and `group_right()` modifiers.

For example, `metric_awesome{instance="one"} - ignoring(instance) metric_awesom{instance="two"}` instructs to ignore `instance` label during searching for time series pairs with identical labels. This may result in multiple-to-one matching, when multiple time series on one side of `-` match a single time series on the another side. By default Prometheus returns error in this case. This can be fixed by adding `group_left()` or `group_right()` modifiers to `-` operator:

```
metric_awesome{instance="one"}
  - ignoring(instance) group_left()
metric_awesome{instance="two"}
```

or

```
metric_awesome{instance="one"}
  - ignoring(instance) group_right()
metric_awesome{instance="two"}
```

See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#many-to-one-and-one-to-many-vector-matches) for more details on these modifiers.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone searches this wanting to do this for a one-to-many subtraction, have a look at `group_right` additionally to what was written before.

```
metric_awesome{instance="one"} - ignoring(instance) group_right metric_awesome{job="compare-instances"}
```

See also [Prometheus documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#many-to-one-and-one-to-many-vector-matches)