# Subtract rate and a sum of rates

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

Having a network transmit metric e.g. `node_network_transmit_bytes_total` from `nodeexporter` I'd like to get a difference between the transmit rate of an interface (`enp3s0` in my case) and a sum of all bridge interface transmit rates.

I have something like this:

```
irate(node_network_transmit_bytes_total{device="enp3s0"}[1m]) -  irate(node_network_transmit_bytes_total{device=~"br.*"}[1m])
```

but this gives me no datapoints.

**EDIT**

I've tried what [Prometheus/PromQL subtract two gauge metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45005524/prometheus-promql-subtract-two-gauge-metrics) suggests but my case is a bit different because on the right hand side I have more than 1 series.

So this:

```
node_network_transmit_bytes_total{device="enp3s0"} - ignoring(device) node_network_transmit_bytes_total{device=~"br.*"}
```

yields:

> Error executing query: found duplicate series for the match group {instance="192.168.X.Z:9100", job="nodeexporter"} on the right hand-side of the operation: [{**name**="node_network_transmit_bytes_total", device="br-XXXX", instance="192.168.X.Z:9100", job="nodeexporter"}, {**name**="node_network_transmit_bytes_total", device="br-5d6dce95c2b0", instance="192.168.X.Z:9100", job="nodeexporter"}];many-to-many matching not allowed: matching labels must be unique on one side

I've tried using `sum()`:

```
node_network_transmit_bytes_total{device="enp3s0"} - ignoring(device) sum(node_network_transmit_bytes_total{device=~"br.*"})
```

but that yields no results again.

**EDIT2**

I've managed to figure out how to get a difference by

```
sum(node_network_transmit_bytes_total{device="enp3s0"}) by (instance) - sum (node_network_transmit_bytes_total{device=~"br.*"}) by (instance)
```

but I cannot use `irate` on it:

```
irate(sum(node_network_transmit_bytes_total{device="enp3s0"}) by (instance) - sum (node_network_transmit_bytes_total{device=~"br.*"}) by (instance))[5m]
```

> Error executing query: 1:149: parse error: ranges only allowed for vector selectors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prometheus/PromQL subtract two gauge metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45005524/prometheus-promql-subtract-two-gauge-metrics)

Comment: @MichaelDoubez The case I have is a bit different. Please check my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK it seems this was the solution:

```
(sum(irate(node_network_receive_bytes_total{device="enp3s0"}[1m])) by (instance))
 -
(sum(irate(node_network_receive_bytes_total{device=~"br.*"}[1m])) by (instance))
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is recommended to use [rate()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#rate) instead of [irate()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#irate), since `irate()` tends to return jumpy results - see [this article](https://valyala.medium.com/why-irate-from-prometheus-doesnt-capture-spikes-45f9896d7832) for details.

If you want to calculate per-`instance` sum of network transmit rates for devices with names starting with `br`, then the following query must be used:

```
sum(rate(node_network_transmit_bytes_total{device=~"br.*"}[1m])) by (instance)
```

See [sum()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sum) docs for details.

The `rate(node_network_transmit_bytes_total{device="enp3s0"}[1m])` returns per-`instance` network transmit rates for `enp3s0` device. It is likely the returned time series contain additional labels other than `instance` label. So the following query returns empty results because of [time series matching rules for binary operators in Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#one-to-one-vector-matches):

```
rate(node_network_transmit_bytes_total{device="enp3s0"}[1m])
  -
sum(rate(node_network_transmit_bytes_total{device=~"br.*"}[1m])) by (instance)
```

This can be fixed in two ways:

1. To wrap the `rate(node_network_transmit_bytes_total{device="enp3s0"}[1m])` into `sum(...) by (instance)`. This effectively removes all the labels other than `instance` from result and allows finding time series pairs with identical sets of labels on the left and the right side of `-`:

```
sum(rate(node_network_transmit_bytes_total{device="enp3s0"}[1m])) by (instance)
  -
sum(rate(node_network_transmit_bytes_total{device=~"br.*"}[1m])) by (instance)
```

2. To add `on (instance)` modifier after `-` operator:

```
rate(node_network_transmit_bytes_total{device="enp3s0"}[1m])
  - on (instance)
sum(rate(node_network_transmit_bytes_total{device=~"br.*"}[1m])) by (instance)
```

This will preserve all the original labels for `node_network_transmit_bytes_total` time series. See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#many-to-one-and-one-to-many-vector-matches) for details on `on()` modifier.